# How send @property to another class which can work with it to get the actual value of property in Python

Tags: python, properties, pass-by-reference

This is my way to solve the problem. But I hope there is a way easier and more beautiful. I do not know all about Python yet, but I did not get any answers to this question - questions and answers were about another. Perhaps I was looking badly or there is a completely different approach that does not need references. I need that the class to which passed the link to a property, always could receive its value independently, without receiving additional reminders, and furthermore direct values.

```
class SomeObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self._someproperty =None
        self.somepropertyRef=SomeObject.__dict__['someproperty'] # reference
    @property # I need pass property as a parameter like a function
    def someproperty(self): 
        return self._someproperty
    @someproperty.setter
    def someproperty(self, someproperty): 
        self._someproperty = someproperty

so = SomeObject()

# 1) example without using ref 
so.someproperty="123"
temp = so.someproperty
print(temp == so.someproperty) # True
so.someproperty=0
print(temp == so.someproperty) # Of course, False!

# 2) example with using ref 
temp = (so.somepropertyRef, so) # Oh...
print(temp[0].fget(temp[1]) == so.someproperty) # True. But long way...
so.someproperty="456"
print(temp[0].fget(temp[1]) == so.someproperty) # True. How to do the same easy?
```

Comment: are you asking about [reflection](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reflection-in-python/)?

Comment: I think I need just byref value. For example, I can assign an external function to a class variable and always be able to call it inside this class. Or for example , I have an array, when I change the value of some index, then having a reference to this array and index, I can find out a new value if I need it

Comment: some kind of data binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeObject.someproperty` is the reference you are looking for. Properties are class attributes with special behavior when, among other things, invoked from an instance of the class.

```
temp = (SomeObject.someproperty, so)
```

You can also save the reference to `SomeObject.someproperty.fget` if all you want is access to the value.

```
temp = (SomeObject.someproperty.fget, so)
print(temp[0](temp[1]) == so.someproperty)
so.foo = 456
print(temp[0](temp[1]) == so.someproperty)
```

Comment: it works, but is it possible to do with one parameter, not two? I do not need to know to which object the property belongs, but to get the value, unfortunately, I need to pass the object (extra parameter temp[1])

Comment: Properties don't belong to objects, just classes. Its behavior is determined by what gets passed to the descriptors `__get__` method. Would `t = functools.partial(SomeObject.property.fget, so)` work? Then `t() == so.someproperty`.

Comment: Thank you! It looks more elegant